# I am trouble getting my esp32 working on Linux

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-ide, arduino-esp32

I am using garuda linux specifically. Im getting this error

> `Sketch uses 227017 bytes (17%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.
> Global variables use 21760 bytes (6%) of dynamic memory, leaving 305920 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 327680 bytes.
> esptool.py v4.2.1
> Serial port /dev/ttyUSB0

> A fatal error occurred: Could not open /dev/ttyUSB0, the port doesn't exist
> A fatal error occurred: Could not open /dev/ttyUSB0, the port doesn't exist
> `

The usb0 port shows up when i plug in the esp32, and im able to select it on arduino. So it obviously does exist. So i thought maybe i dont have the cp2102 driver. I try to install it, and i get this error

> make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=/home/sovadirr/Desktop/espdriv modules
> make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/lib/modules/6.0.9-zen1-1-zen/build'
> CC [M]  /home/sovadirr/Desktop/espdriv/cp210x.o
> /home/sovadirr/Desktop/espdriv/cp210x.c:290:35: error: initialization of ‘void (*)(struct usb_serial_port *)’ from incompatible pointer type ‘int (*)(struct usb_serial_port *)’ [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
> 290 |         .port_remove            = cp210x_port_remove,
> |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> /home/sovadirr/Desktop/espdriv/cp210x.c:290:35: note: (near initialization for ‘cp210x_device.port_remove’)
> cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
> make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:249: /home/sovadirr/Desktop/espdriv/cp210x.o] Error 1
> make[1]: *** [Makefile:1849: /home/sovadirr/Desktop/espdriv] Error 2
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/lib/modules/6.0.9-zen1-1-zen/build'
> make: *** [Makefile:7: all] Error 2

I am very confused, because would the esp32 not show on arduino if i didnt have the driver? I believe i have the esp32 devkit v1, it says on the back of the board.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

***rom incompatible pointer type ‘int ()(struct usb_serial_port *)’ [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]***

From the looks of it, this has happened in OpenSuSE, Debian, Manjaro, and Arch.
This is a fix for Putty. I'm not sure how to apply it to the esp32 driver. I don't have much time, so don't expect results from me today. I'm not any expert. I'm just sharing my attempts.
https://github.com/xmm7360/xmm7360-pci/pull/159

These links seem to work on the issue. Watch out for the few that just turn the errors off.
https://github.com/xmm7360/xmm7360-pci/issues/141

https://github.com/xmm7360/xmm7360-pci/issues/137

Thanks,
Pat